# HTML5 canvas faster fillText() vs drawImage()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a digital clock that is running and being updated every 10 milliseconds. In each draw call I am using this:

```
    var gradient = clockContext.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, this.digitWidth);
    gradient.addColorStop(0.15, "rgb(255, 252, 52)");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.15, "rgb(245, 127, 26)");
    gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(248, 159, 52)");
    clockContext.fillStyle = gradient;
    clockContext.lineWidth = 1;
    clockContext.lineStyle = "#000000";
    clockContext.fillText(time, (this.digitWidth * i) + e + s, 46);
    clockContext.strokeText(time, (this.digitWidth * i) + e + s, 46);
```

Now is this quicker or slow than creating a PNG of the numbers 0 - 9, caching each one and then using `drawImage()` on each draw call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drawImage` is always, *always* faster than `fillText`. It can be 100+ times faster depending on how the text is constructed.

I did a meandering analysis here not long ago:

http://simonsarris.com/blog/322-canvas-drawtext-considered-harmful

Here's a simple jsperf example: http://jsperf.com/image-vs-text

Comment: Now with drawImage. Would it be better to draw 0 - 9 in separate canvases and then to the main canvas or to draw them directly to the main canvas?

Comment: Holy flipping cow. That made my application so much smoother and quicker. Thank you for the examples!

Comment: just make a single PNG with 0123456789 and draw that PNG directly to the main Canvas (well, part of that PNG).

Comment: blog link is 404, copy from archive.org https://web.archive.org/web/20160803112533/http://simonsarris.com/blog/322-canvas-drawtext-considered-harmful